# Django - .save() not saving data to DB

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to create a page where a user can select 17 soccer players and save to their profile, using a ModelForm.

**The form**

```
class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['GK1', 'GK2', 'DF1', 'DF2', 'DF3', 'DF4', 'DF5', 'MF1', 'MF2', 'MF3', 'MF4', 'MF5', 'FW1', 'FW2', 'FW3']
```

**The View**

```
def selectteam(request):
print('request.post=', request.POST)
print(request.user)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        print("form confirmed valid") #let me know that the data is valid
        form.user = request.user      #set the user's data we are changing
        form.save()                   #save the form to db
        for x in form.cleaned_data:   #check what the data is???
            print(x)
        return redirect('/accounts/profile/selectteam')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        form = ProfileForm()
else:
    selectedplayers = Player.objects.all()
    # if not, you need an empty form for GET request
    form = ProfileForm()
    context = {'selectedplayers': selectedplayers, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'selectteam.html', context)
```

For the life of me, I cannot get the data to actually submit. Here's the **console output:**

```
[28/Apr/2018 10:27:33] "GET /static/images/pitch.png HTTP/1.1" 200 40216
request.post= <QueryDict: {'MF1': ['301'], 'MF2': ['301'], 'GK1': ['301'], 'DF5': ['301'], 'FW1': ['301'], 'DF1': ['301'], 'MF3': ['301'], 'FW2': ['301'], 'GK2': ['301'], 'MF5': ['301'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['RtvpMLuPVXaupYNzJdt1yvuJsOhfouH51FUQw73IRzUnKqZRLkzcNHWvoMFyVX4N'], 'DF4': ['301'], 'DF3': ['301'], 'DF2': ['301'], 'FW3': ['301'], 'MF4': ['301']}>
request.method= POST
Johnny
form confirmed valid
GK1
GK2
DF1
DF2
DF3
DF4
DF5
MF1
MF2
MF3
MF4
MF5
FW1
FW2
FW3
```

So I can see that form.is_valid() is returning TRUE. I can see what data is trying to be saved. I can also see the fields that have supposedly been changed.

However when I go into the admin console and check the user "Johnny" - the fields are still blank/default! I am really confused as all my checking and validation seems to be fine.

My only guess is that the data the form is actually sending doesn't "fit" the available choices. For example it may be trying to select the value ['301'] yet within my list of options the real value would be 301. Perhaps I should do some form of data_cleaning? I just don't know! The field generated by the modelform is for example:

```
GK1 = models.ForeignKey('players.PlayerID', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='+')
```

Can anyone spot if I'm doing something incorrect? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`form.user` doesn't have any effect on created object. To add current user to created object you can do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)  
    print("form confirmed valid") #let me know that the data is valid
    obj.user = request.user      #set the user's data we are changing
    obj.save()
    return redirect('/accounts/profile/selectteam')
```

You can find details about `commit` argument and examples [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

**UPD**

Also `request.user` is instance of `User` model, but you need to provide to `ProfileForm` profile instance. So if you not set [`AUTH_USER_MODEL=Profile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model), you should do something like this in view:

```
form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
```

Comment: The UPD is exactly it :) I've got to admit I'm too noob-ish to get why request.user does not work but request.user.profile does. Thanks again, this has been spinning my head for 3 days!